# Creating grid and interpolating (x,y,z) for contour plot sagemath

Tags: numpy, scipy, interpolation, contour, sage

!I have values in the form of (x,y,z). By creating a list_plot3d plot i can clearly see that they are not quite evenly spaced. They usually form little "blobs" of 3 to 5 points on the xy plane. So for the interpolation and the final "contour" plot to be better, or should i say smoother(?), do i have to create a rectangular grid (like the squares on a chess board) so that the blobs of data are somehow "smoothed"? I understand that this might be trivial to some people but i am trying this for the first time and i am struggling a bit. I have been looking at the scipy packages like scipy.interplate.interp2d but the graphs produced at the end are really bad. Maybe a brief tutorial on 2d interpolation in sagemath for an amateur like me? Some advice? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bxv8ab9PeMQVUFhBYWlldU9ib0E/edit?pli=1

This is mostly the kind of graphs it produces along with this message:

```
Warning:     No more knots can be added because the number of B-spline
coefficients
    already exceeds the number of data points m. Probably causes:
either
    s or m too small. (fp>s)
    kx,ky=3,3 nx,ny=17,20 m=200 fp=4696.972223 s=0.000000
```

To get this graph i just run this command:

```
f_interpolation = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(*zip(*matrix(C)),kind='cubic')
               plot_interpolation = contour_plot(lambda x,y:
                   f_interpolation(x,y)[0], (22.419,22.439),(37.06,37.08) ,cmap='jet', contours=numpy.arange(0,1400,100), colorbar=True)

               plot_all = plot_interpolation

               plot_all.show(axes_labels=["m", "m"])
```

Where matrix(c) can be a huge matrix like 10000 X 3 or even a lot more like 1000000 x 3. The problem of bad graphs persists even with fewer data like the picture i attached now where matrix(C) was only 200 x 3. That's why i begin to think that it could be that apart from a possible glitch with the program my approach to the use of this command might be totally wrong, hence the reason for me to ask for advice about using a grid and not just "throwing" my data into a command.

Comment: Can you post the plot, and describe what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar problem using the scipy.interpolate.interp2d function. My understanding is that the issue arises because the interp1d/interp2d and related functions use an older wrapping of FITPACK for the underlying calculations. I was able to get a problem similar to yours to work using the spline functions, which rely on a newer wrapping of FITPACK. The spline functions can be identified because they seem to all have capital letters in their names here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html. Within the scipy installation, these newer functions appear to be located in scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.py, while the functions using the older wrappings are in fitpack.py.

For your purposes, RectBivariateSpline is what I believe you want. Here is some sample code for implementing RectBivariateSpline:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

# Generate unevenly spaced x/y data for axes
npoints = 25
maxaxis = 100
x = (np.random.rand(npoints)*maxaxis) - maxaxis/2.
y = (np.random.rand(npoints)*maxaxis) - maxaxis/2.
xsort = np.sort(x)
ysort = np.sort(y)

# Generate the z-data, which first requires converting
# x/y data into grids
xg, yg = np.meshgrid(xsort,ysort)
z = xg**2 - yg**2

# Generate the interpolated, evenly spaced data
# Note that the min/max of x/y isn't necessarily 0 and 100 since
# randomly chosen points were used. If we want to avoid extrapolation,
# the explicit min/max must be found
interppoints = 100
xinterp = np.linspace(xsort[0],xsort[-1],interppoints)
yinterp = np.linspace(ysort[0],ysort[-1],interppoints)

# Generate the kernel that will be used for interpolation
# Note that the default version uses three coefficients for
# interpolation (i.e. parabolic, a*x**2 + b*x +c). Higher order
# interpolation can be used by setting kx and ky to larger 
# integers, i.e. interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(xsort,ysort,z,kx=5,ky=5)
kernel = interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(xsort,ysort,z)

# Now calculate the linear, interpolated data
zinterp = kernel(xinterp, yinterp)
```

Comment: It looks like this question can also be solved with a related function, scipy.interpolate.griddata: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348708/2d-interpolation-in-python-with-random-spot?lq=1

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I still don't understand this. Maybe a simpler question would be better to clear things up.If the values i have are let's say (longtitude,latitude,altitude) and i just want a contour plot with the same height contours, what would i do in sagemath? Would i use interp2d,RectBivariateSpline or something else?

Comment: I've never used sagemath, but assuming all the function calls are the same (I have no idea), the last two lines of code are what you'd need to interpolate the data. That was the point of this script. Contour plots require the longitude and latitude data to be a grid of identical size as the altitude, so you'll have to use numpy's meshgrid command and then plot the data using matplotlib's contour plot. The plotting of contour plots has been covered on this website in a number of questions.

Comment: There's an example in the scipy cookbook that uses griddata and plots two different types of contour plots here: http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Gridding_irregularly_spaced_data that uses the griddata command I mentioned above. Interestingly, there's no meshgrid command required. I swear I've always had to use it but maybe I am mistaken or this requirement has changed since I last checked. Again, I haven't touched sagemath, so you'll have to figure out how these commands are mapped to the namespace there.

Comment: After running the griddata cookbook example above, I realized why there's no meshgrid command--it's because the z data is also a 1D array. Thus I was only partly incorrect about the use of meshgrid. The  x/y/z data that goes in contour must be the same size. If z data is linear, then x and y must be. But if z is an M x N matrix and x is linear of length N, and y is linear of length M, then meshgrid must be used.